# FFT (installTap) with offline rendering

Tags: ios, swift, fft, core-audio, avaudioengine

I found [examples](https://deezer.io/real-time-music-visualization-on-the-iphone-gpu-579d631272d3) to perform FFT analysis on playing music using `AVAudioNode.installTap` but I wonder how to do it but offline (one off) on a file.

I tried to set 1024 as `maximumFrameCount`:

```swift
let maxNumberOfFrames: AVAudioFrameCount = 1024;
try engine.enableManualRenderingMode(.offline, format: format, maximumFrameCount: maxNumberOfFrames)
```

But the amount of renderings seem quite small (like 1200 instead of the 5000 I get in JavaScript with the builtin audio analysis features).

Am I missing something? Should I perhaps do the FFT directly on the file without the offline rendering? How?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to perform the FFT on the file after you render it?

Comment: @SamBing perform FFT on the file in general (non in real-time, as fast as possible)

Comment: @Nuthinking did you find any solution for this problem? I'm having the same kind of issue too...

Comment: @DEADBEEF using AVAudioEngine with offline render

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to perform analysis and not modify the sound buffers for playback I would suggest looking at `AVAudioSinkNode`. You may find old solutions using `engine.mainMixerNode.installBus()` but that is inefficient for a rapid FFT as it is not in **real** realtime.

Comment: `AVAudioSinkNode` seems to be available only for macOS 10.15+. Do you other alternative rather than `engine.mainMixerNode.installBus()` ?